# Unable to plot Bifurcation diagram of duffing equation

Tags: differential-equations

```
    bifurcation[dmin_, dmax_, nd_, gamma_, A_, ndrop_, nplot_, 
  psize_] := (T = 2*Pi/omega;
  g[{xold_, vold_}] := {x[T], v[T]} /. 
    NDSolve[{v'[t] == 
        0.847 x[t] - 0.0721 x[t]^3 - gamma*v[t] + A*Cos[omega*t], 
       x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == xold, v[0] == vold}, {x, v}, {t, 0, 
       T}][[1]];
  f[{x_, y_}] := {omega, x};
  ListPlot[
   Flatten[Table[
     f /@ Drop[NestList[g, {1, 0}, nplot + ndrop], ndrop], {omega, 
      dmin, dmax, (dmax - dmin)/nd}], 1], 
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize[psize], Hue[0]}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "x"}, AxesOrigin -> {dmin, -0.3}])


bifurcation[0.1, 0.8, 200, 0.01, 0.00172, 1200, 500, 0.006]
```

I am expecting chaos around somewhere near omega=0.45 but instead I am getting just straight line.[image: Straight line bifurcation diagram for given parameters]

Comment: For reference: https://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch3/duffing.html

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right parameter values?  The page @Syed linked to has e.g. `A = 0.4`.  Your value of `A = 0.00172` might be too low to see chaotic behavior.